# VBA Excel 2013 Regex to remove tags brackets leaving tags names

Tags: regex, tags

bI trying to extract tags name

I want get from string with regex

```
if input string <html>vfdg</html> get => html vfdg html
if input string <html> get => html
if input string </html> get => html
```

Now I using regex `"<[^>]+>"` but it cut tags with names. so how to regex to leave tag names?

Comment: which language are you working on ?

Comment: And what should `<html> I love placing angulars and slashes like >, < and like this / </html>` return?

Comment: html I love placing angulars and slashes like , and like this html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong tool for the job. Getting regex to correctly parse HTML is notoriously difficult. Look into an html parser instead. Every modern language should have a library to do this.